# Python Error:Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly while writing to a json file

Tags: python, json

I have a json file out of which one field has list data as shown below
{
"broker_address":"0.0.0.0",
"serial_id": "YYMMSSSSSSVV",
"auto_foc": true,
"timer": [0,23,30]
}

I am taking user input for timer field so I want to replace the timer data with the input value received from user. On trying it I am getting following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 23, in <module>
    time, final)
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

My code snippet is as follows

```
import json
import os
import time

val = input("Enter your value: ")
print(val)
str1 = " "
with open('/home/pi/config.json', 'r+') as filer:
    print("file read")
    az = filer.read()
    print(az)
    read_file = az.rstrip('/n')
    data = json.loads(read_file)
    #print("printing file",json.loads(read_file))
    time=data["timer"]
    #print(read_file)
    print(time)
    print("Waiting.....................")
    #time.sleep(2)
    final = str(val)
    print(final)
    read_file = read_file.replace(
        time, final)

with open('/home/pi/config.json', 'w') as filer:
    filer.write(read_file)
```

Please let me know how to resolve this error.

Comment: how about just doing `read_file = read_file.replace(time, list(final))`

Comment: Hi sammy, this doesn't work but the following solution given by @An0n1m1ty works fine. Thank you for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import json
import os
import time

val = input("Enter your value: ")
print(val)
str1 = " "
with open('/home/pi/config.json', 'r+') as filer:
    print("file read")
    az = filer.read()
    print(az)
    read_file = az.rstrip('/n')
    data = json.loads(read_file)
    #print("printing file",json.loads(read_file))
    time=data["timer"]
    #print(read_file)
    print(time)
    print("Waiting.....................")
    #time.sleep(2)
    final = str(val).split()
    final = [int(i) for i in final] 
    print(final)
    print(str(time))
    read_file = read_file.replace(str(time), str(final))
    print(read_file)

with open('/home/pi/config.json', 'w') as filer:
    filer.write(read_file)
```

And update the json file from `"timer": [0,23,30]` to `"timer": [0, 23, 30]` i.e. add spaces

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225393/discussion-on-answer-by-an0n1m1ty-python-errorcant-convert-list-object-to-st).

Answer (score 0):

One thing avoid using the name `time` when you use that name as a variable it will replace the imported name time. Secondly the issue is that the data is a list not a string and replace is expecting a string not a list.

What you will want to do is just take advantage of json for what it is a serializer and deserializer and modify the data itself and use json to write it to a file. This also ensures you will be able to read it back out as json.

```
import json
import os
import time

val = input("Enter your value: ")
print(val)
str1 = " "
with open('/home/pi/config.json', 'r+') as filer:
    print("file read")
    data = json.load(filer)
    timer=data["timer"] #DONT USE time
    print(timer)
    print("Waiting.....................")
    #time.sleep(2)
    final = str(val)
    print(final)
    #This next part will be up to you, 
    # do you want this to be the list it was before?
    # or the string as input
    data['timer'] = final

with open('/home/pi/config.json', 'w') as filer:
    json.dump(data,filer)
```